# Timezone parsing from date in string gives empty string

Tags: go, time, timezone

I want to parse a date (having timezone) represented by a string into `Time`.

I tried the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {   
    dateString := "Sat Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2021"
    dateTime, _ := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006", dateString)
    
    zoneName, _ := dateTime.Zone()
    fmt.Println("Zone Name is "+ zoneName)
    
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation(zoneName)
    fmt.Println(loc)
}
```

On running the code I am getting the `zoneName` as empty string which eventually transforms into `UTC` whereas I should be getting a valid time zone? What mistake have I done to parse the date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang time zone parsing not returning the correct zone on ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740401/golang-time-zone-parsing-not-returning-the-correct-zone-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090669/golang-empty-location-on-mac-osx-when-parsing-time

Comment: What zone are you expecting? There is no name for `-0700`, it could align with any of be MST, MT, PDT or T

Comment: side-note: you can parse this format conveniently with `time.Parse(time.RubyDate, dateString)`, see [time/Constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Comment: and see also [Time Zone != Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) regarding why the location *should* in fact be empty

Comment: I tried few things based on comments from @mkrieger. time.Parse gives timezone when the date in string has the same timezone as that of the server. Has anyone tried doing the same on their local machine?